# SNI and hostname provided via HTTP are different error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, aws

I am using Apache 2.2 webserver on ubuntu Aws instance. My website goes down with below errors on error log,

> [ssl:error] [pid 46283] AH02032: Hostname  provided via SNI and hostname  provided via HTTP are different
>
> [ssl:error] [pid 50376] AH02031: Hostname  provided via SNI, but no hostname provided in HTTP request

Many website shows it might be some attack, How can I solve this issue ?

> can we block such request by adding any rule on htaccess or vhost ?

Comment: It looks like someone is purposefully or accidentally using [Domain Fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_fronting) against your site. This could be just a bad / misconfigured bot, but it can also be used to perform certain kinds of attacks.

Comment: @vcsjones How can I prevent such attack

Comment: There is no problem, as your server did nothing but log an error. Programs sending broken data aren't uncommon. Probably some bot crawling ips without knowing the associated domain.